# How to check all values for a particular column in a week

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring, hibernate3

i have a table called timesheet.In that i has below rows

```
  ID Status ProjId ActId  Date
    1  pending  1     1     2014-aug-07
    2  denied   1     2     2014-aug-08
    3  saved    1     3     2014-aug-09
    4  approved 1     4     2014-aug-10
```

i have used below query for getting the desired result.

```
SELECT * from tblTimesheet 
WHERE DATEPART(wk,spentDate) = 32 AND ((timesheetstatus = 'Pending' or timesheetstatus = 'Approved') and (timesheetstatus <> 'Saved' or timesheetstatus <> 'Denied'))
```

My expected result for the above query is 0.But i get the  result is 1.

```
 5  pending  1     1     2014-aug-11
    6  pending  1     2     2014-aug-12
    7  approved 1     3     2014-aug-13
    8  approved 1     4     2014-aug-14
```

this case my query works.

```
SELECT * from tblTimesheet 
WHERE DATEPART(wk,spentDate) = 32 AND ((timesheetstatus = 'Pending' or timesheetstatus = 'Approved') and (timesheetstatus <> 'Saved' or timesheetstatus <> 'Denied'))
```

My expected result for the above query is 1.I get the  result is 1.

How to write the query for above requirement in mssql.
Scenario 1 is worked.But scenario2 is not worked.
How to acheive the desired result.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: There is only one row for week 32, right?

Comment: no,one week has many rows

Comment: But not in your example

Comment: 2014-aug-03 to 2014-aug-10 is week 32 based on datepart function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is a solution for mysql, because that was also tagged. It uses MySQL's standard defintion for a 'week' - which appears to differ fron your own definition. You may be able to use WEEK(date,3) or something similar if that better matches your definition.

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,Status VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,ProjId INT NOT NULL
,ActId INT NOT NULL
,Date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1  ,'pending',1     ,1     ,'2014-08-07'),
(2  ,'denied',   1     ,2     ,'2014-08-08'),
(3  ,'saved',    1     ,3     ,'2014-08-09'),
(4  ,'approved', 1     ,4     ,'2014-08-10');

SELECT *,WEEK(date) FROM my_table;
+----+----------+--------+-------+------------+------------+
| ID | Status   | ProjId | ActId | Date       | WEEK(date) |
+----+----------+--------+-------+------------+------------+
|  1 | pending  |      1 |     1 | 2014-08-07 |         31 |
|  2 | denied   |      1 |     2 | 2014-08-08 |         31 |
|  3 | saved    |      1 |     3 | 2014-08-09 |         31 |
|  4 | approved |      1 |     4 | 2014-08-10 |         32 |
+----+----------+--------+-------+------------+------------+

SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON WEEK(y.date) = WEEK(x.date) 
   AND y.status NOT IN ('approved','pending') 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
+----+----------+--------+-------+------------+
| ID | Status   | ProjId | ActId | Date       |
+----+----------+--------+-------+------------+
|  4 | approved |      1 |     4 | 2014-08-10 |
+----+----------+--------+-------+------------+
```

Edit: Result with WEEK(date,3)...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON WEEK(y.date,3) = WEEK(x.date,3) 
   AND y.status NOT IN ('approved','pending') 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks..  How to find status only in pending or approved for a particular week. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. Consider providing a more comprehensive data set, and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblTimesheet 
WHERE YEARWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(Date,"%Y-%M-%d"))=YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) AND (status='pending' or status='approved');
```

Comment: it returns the value 1.but i want zero.you should check any status for that day is denied or saved

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Select * from 
(
SELECT * from tblTimesheet 
WHERE DATEPART(wk,spentDate) = 32 
AND (timesheetstatus = 'Pending' or timesheetstatus = 'Approved')
)tbl 
where
 (timesheetstatus <> 'Saved' or timesheetstatus <> 'Denied'
```